# Increasing OCR accuracy with tesseract? (Python)

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

Im trying to build some simple script to auto-farm on a game.

Basically in-game I train until I reach a certain percentage of a stat called Body Fatigue thats always on the screen. What I would like to happen is detect when it reaches 60% and store that number in a variable so I can work with it. I tried using tesseract's image_to_string function with a snippet taken but it displays the wrong info because of the weird font of the text. I'll put the picture here as well and any info would be appreciated![image: percentage example]

I tried rescaling the picture x2 and it seems to be improving but its still doing critical mistakes that could ruin the thing ex taking 5 as a $ or 6 as 0.
The following code is supposed to find a saved image snippet called **BodyFatigue.png** in the region determined by the **reg** tuple. It returns the coordinates (top, left, width, height) to **reg2** then saves a .PNG of the **reg2** region.

I was supposed to extract the percentage number and use it in some further code but I'm having difficulties with tesseract's text recognition, I think its because of the weird font.

```
import pyautogui as pag
import pytesseract as pyt
from PIL import Image

pyt.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

reg = 0, 197, 841, 146

reg2 = pag.locateOnScreen('resources/BodyFatigue.png', region = reg, confidence = 0.4, grayscale = True)
bdftg = pag.screenshot('resources/BFNew.png', region = reg2)

new_size = tuple(2*x for x in bdftg.size) 
bdftg = bdftg.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
output = pyt.image_to_string(bdftg)

print(output)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the font available ?

Comment: @Kendle I don't think I can get hold of it since its not a game I can have access to its files (it's a Roblox game btw)

Comment: Figure out how to distinguish each character manually by checking some pixels, then advance the corresponding width (determined by measuring manually!) and repeat. That should be very efficient if there’s no fancy kerning going on. Otherwise, split into connected white shapes (it looks like they don’t overlap, thanks to the black outline) and use the same approach.

Comment: tesseract can get better result if you can create better image but you rather can't get better screenshot. But PyAutoGUI shoud have method to compare images and you could use it to recognize every digit on screen and create value. See also [Programming a Bot to Play the "Sushi Go Round" Flash Game - The Invent with Python Blog](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/)

Comment: tesseract doc: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)